# Does returning mysqli_error() in console log pose website a security risk?

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I have a simple website form through which a can input data (name, address, password, whatever - it is not important).
I use a jQuery ajax call to send the submitted data to a PHP file that in turn, validates the data and  adds it to a database.

Does returning `mysqli_error()` in the ajax results pose a security risk? For example, an error message may expose the database name or field names in the console log.

Is it acceptable in production or should I could send all errors to file with `error_log()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exposing this information poses a security risk. This applies to all PHP errors, not only mysqli ones. This is why you should disable `display_errors` in production.

Using `mysqli_error()` carries additional risk as the way you are using it probably does not obey that directive. If your code has any SQL injection, exposed errors are a cherry on top. They not only expose code, but also data.

The best way is to never use this function. Just enable [automatic mysqli error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) and treat them like any other PHP error. Even in development, it's unnecessary and cumbersome to check for errors manually.